# "function" object has no attribute "SVC"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn 0.23.1, running on the conda python 3.7 interpreter,  and I keep getting the above AttributeError when I run the following lines

```
from sklearn import svm
svm_model = svm.SVC()
```

Comment: Good practice in sklearn is to only import what you need, like `from sklearn.svm import SVC`

Comment: someone should tell whoever updates the documentation that https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#classification

Comment: Fair point, but still a good practice. As for your specific situation, it seems likely that you already have a variable or function manually defined that is shadowing the imported `svm`. You can try `print(svm)` or just `del svm` then re-import and see if that fixes it

Comment: Your solution alone worked, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just use the import statement `from sklearn.svm import SVC`, as suggested by G. Anderson